# Check if a specific file in a folder exists in another - Shellscript

Tags: shell

Im starting shellscripting and i'm having trouble with a script.
So, i have two folers (doesn't matter the kind of files i have in them) and i need to check if the files on folder1 exists in folder 2. If do, check if its modified date is more recent.

This is what i have:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `find $1 -type f`
do
    for j in `find $2 -type f`
    do
        if [ -e $2/$i ]
        then
            if [ $i -ot $j ]
            then
                echo File "`basename $i`" its newer and it will be copied
            else
                echo File is updated
            fi
        else
            echo "`basename $i`" will be copied because it doesn't exist
        fi
    done
done
```

$1 and $2 are the folder arguments

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
With 3 files in folder1 and one of them (file2) in folder 2 i get this output.

i had 3 files in folder1 and one of them was also in folder2 and i got (file2 was in both folders):

```
file1 will be copied because it doesn't exist
file2 will be copied because it doesn't exist
file2 will be copied because it doesn't exist
file1 will be copied because it doesn't exist
file3 will be copied because it doesn't exist
file3 will be copied because it doesn't exist
```

Comment: Why it does not work? What's the output?

Comment: i had 3 files in folder1 and one of them was also in folder2 and i got (file2 was in both folders):

`file1 will be copied because it doesn't exist
file2 will be copied because it doesn't exist
file2 will be copied because it doesn't exist
file1 will be copied because it doesn't exist
file3 will be copied because it doesn't exist
file3 will be copied because it doesn't exist`

Comment: Please, update post and paste script output.

Comment: Done. Pasted the output

Answer (score 0):

Two things are wrong in that script:
A. You don't need nested for loop, because you are doing some checking against each file in first directory, not for each file in first directory and respectively each file in scond directory (that's why you have so much files displayed).
B. When you use find to get files in directory you don't need the path, just filename, which existence you will check in second directory.

Here's the fixed version. Let me know whether is solves your problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `find $1 -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort`;
do
  if [ -e "$2/$i" ]
  then
    if [ "$1/$i" -ot "$2/$i" ]
    then
      echo "File basename $i its newer and it will be copied"
    else
      echo "File is updated"
    fi
  else
    echo "basename $i will be copied because it doesn't exist"
  fi
done
```